# Improving spinner performance to stop android app crashing

Tags: android, xamarin, spinner

I am practicing developing Xamarin android applications and I have an issue regarding app crashing when I handle listviews and spinners with a lot of data. If there is anyone that can explain me how to reuse views in these objects i would be very grateful.
Thanks in advance.. :)

My code:
This is my code in listview case.

```
    ApiServices l = new ApiServices(); 
    List<string> items = l.FromOrToPale("Pale"); 
    var adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, 
    Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleExpandableListItem1, items); 

    _listView = new ListView(this) { Adapter = adapter };
```

And this is in spinner case

```
    ApiServices l = new ApiServices(); 
    List<string> items = l.FromOrToPale("Pale"); 
    var adapter = new ArrayAdapter( this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, items); 
    adapter.SetDropDownViewResource(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItemActivated1‌​); 

    dropdown.Adapter = adapter;
```

Comment: Are you using an `ArrayAdapter` (or subclass of) by any chance? Those have terrible performance on Xamarin.Android.

Comment: I am using adapter and I realized that it slows app's performance, so I need example of another ways to fill spinners and listview:)

Comment: The adapter pattern isn't the problem, `ArrayAdapter` just has significantly worse performance due to marshaling to and from JNI. Can you include the code for your current adapter? I can help you identify issues in your existing code.

Comment: ApiServices l = new ApiServices();
List<string> items = l.FromOrToPale("Pale");
var adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleExpandableListItem1, items);
_listView = new ListView(this) { Adapter = adapter };

This is my code in listview case.

var adapter = new ArrayAdapter(
                this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, items);
            adapter.SetDropDownViewResource(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItemActivated1);
dropdown.Adapter = adapter;

And this is in spinner case.

Comment: Please put it in the question and format as code... That's really hard to read.

Comment: Sorry... Now I did it

Comment: This [tutorial from Xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/working_with_listviews_and_adapters/part_2_-_populating_a_listview_with_data/#Implementing_a_ListAdapter) might help.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks man a lot. :)